# TCPDF strange output

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) to generate PDF's. They are one page with two PNG images inserted. This is all working fine on my local Ubuntu server but on a remote server the output is strange, see attachment.

No errors are thrown, GD and Imagemagick are enabled. I have also set the memory limit to 2gb and have turned off max execution time. Has anybody got any tips as to why this may be happening?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Just to confirm: On the remote server, php is set to display all warnings, and notices right? (And zero are showing up)?

Comment: At the top of the script (which is run via CLI) is         `error_reporting(E_ALL); display_errors(1);` so any errors should be being thrown.

Comment: hmmmm.... and your versions of php are identical?

Comment: Exactly the same. It's strange because the PDF obviously gets generated and an image (of sorts) is inserted into the page.

Comment: Is your entire pdf text? If not, are the non-text parts showing up weird too?

Comment: The PDF is one page with two images on it - there is no text. The output you see is the images. The output should not look as 'corrupt' as that.

Comment: The TCPDF alpha transparency example works so I am thinking it must be something to do with the way I am running the script.

Comment: _“but on a remote server the output is strange, see attachment”_ – and what would be “not strange”, opposed to what you have shown us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By forcing TCPDF to use the GD library instead fixed my problem.